# Manipulate form controls from same application in a different pc with button click event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lan

Im using `MySql` as my database. I want to change text of label of userpc on button click of adminpc. The computers are connected via LAN

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgse)
{
      string query = "SELECT bar FROM tblfoobar WHERE id = ?id";
      con.OpenConnection
      using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,con.connection))
      {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id",number);
            using(MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                  while(mdr.Read())
                  {
                       lblbar.Text = mdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

It should change the `lblbar.Text` in userpc when adminpc presses `button1`

Comment: There is no 'easy' way to do this. I would suggest changing the userpc to poll the database periodically. In the database, store the `number` that the adminpc has selected.

Comment: Problem with this, the `label` is already set when the timer ticks. I want it to only be set when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i have 2 options on my mind:

- Create UPDATE table in your database with `userid` and `updateString`. Then from admin account insert into that table `userId` you want to update (let's say 3) and `updateString` in format like this `label5|customText'. Then create`Update' class which will be created at your main form and be there all time program is up and have code like this:

Update class:

```
public class Update
{
    private Timer timer1;

    public void Update()
    {            
        public void InitTimer()
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 2000; // in miliseconds
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckForUpate();
        }

        private void CheckForUpdate()
        {
            //Here you connect to your table and do:
            //SELECT UPDATESTRING FROM UPDATE WHERE USERID = THISUSER
            //if(dr.Read()) - if he read something - we will say it got label5|changedText
            string updateStringWeImitate = "label5|changedText"; //this you will get from SELECT

            string[] ss = updateStringWeImitate.Split('|');
            switch(ss[0])
            {
                case "label5":
                label5.Text = ss[1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now every 2 sec it check for update and it will update what you tell him.

- Second option is to use Events in SQL. You create same update table but you do not check for update every 2 sec. I am working with firebird so cannot help you much with this but it looks something like this:

  CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger FOR UPDATE
  ACTIVE AFTER INSERT
  AS
  BEGIN
  POST_EVENT 'update';
  END

and then in your code you have line that listen to events sent from sql and again do the same thing with `switch()`

Comment: Problem with this, the label is already set when the timer ticks. I want it to only be set when the button is clicked.

Comment: It is not set when timer ticks. When timer ticks it check into database if there is row with your `updateString`, but there is not until you press button